# Making prestashop back office theme

Tags: prestashop

I am novice to **Prestashop** and I need to customize **prestashop back office theme** in design and functionality. I just wanted to know is it possible to change the design and back office funtionalities without losing prestashop's basic integrity? And can anyone give some basic idea how I can start it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this guide you can find the answer:

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Characteristics+of+a+back-office+theme

for the back-office theme you need to insert the file edited from /admin/theme/default/templates into /override/controllers/admin/templates.

Hope this can help you

Answer (score 2):

Prestashop is highly customization software. Prestashop gives you ability to change things on the fly.

Making prestashop back office theme is a big topic to cover here on stackoverflow. But still I would give some basic idea how it can be done.

**1)** Copy original back office theme `/admin***/themes/default` theme in the same folder and give it a name you want.

**2)** For global changes related to css in backoffice you can leverage file `/admin***/themes/mytheme/css/override.css`

**3)** As any other traditional php architecture in prestashop also you have main header.tpl and footer.tpl in location `/admin***/themes/mytheme/template`.

**4)** In prestashop for each page in back office you can see controllers in url. In order to make changes to those controller pages. You can look under `admin***/themes/mytheme/template/controllers/controller_you_want_to_modify`.

**5)** If you want to make any change in the controller functionality, you can override that particular controller by copying original controller from `/controllers/admin/controller_you_want_to_change` to `/override/controllers/admin/`. Once done feel free to make any change to controller file.